# MySQL Workbench - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

Here is my script on workbench to import a csv file into a table. My machine is Windows.

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\test.csv"
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

However, I got the following error message. Do I need to do any setting for the local file path?

0   55  11:45:53    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\test.csv"
INTO TABLE test
....   Error Code: 3948. Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides  0.000 sec

Comment: There are a number of things you need to address to use LOAD DATA. Take a look at [the manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) and make sure you've covered all the items in the bullet list part way down.

Comment: Adjust `local_infile` value in server's options file in both [mysqld] and [client] sections.

Comment: I found something from the link of MySql Documentation. See following.

=======================================================
Specify the path in a global or local option file. For example, put the following lines in /etc/my.cnf

[mysqld]
socket=/path/to/socket

[client]
socket=/path/to/socket
=====================================================

I did find that file. Do I have to add these command lines to that file and specify my own path like C:\? But it doesn't allow me to do any change to the file – my.cnf (actually my file name is called "mysqlrouter.conf").